# Setting input value with query string value safely

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, uri

I have an `<input type="text">` and i would like to set it's value to the "q" query string safely. Because if the query string contains a special character `(+,#,...)` , the JS will stop executing.

I have tried `encodeURIComponent()` and `encodeURI()`, but the value in the search box will also be escaped, so you'll get some weird things in the search box.

I also tried `decodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent())` but this will make the JS stop executing.

Also, PHP isn't the solution I want to use, so let's forget PHP GET even if it works.

Try the bug : http://smartsearch.altervista.org/?q=the+plus+character+breaks+the+code

And as you can see the panels don't work anymore (click on the toolbar buttons, they should show a panel). The panels work perfectly when there's no query strings with special characters.

Full code (as some people requested it) :

```
$(function() {
if(getParameter("q") && getParameter("engine")) {
        search(getParameter("q").replace("smartsearch://",""),getParameter("engine"));
    }
    else if(getParameter("engine")) {
        $(".search-engine a[data-engine-shortname="+getParameter("engine")+"]").click();
    }
    else if(getParameter("q")) {
        search(getParameter("q").replace("smartsearch://",""));
    }
    });
// Helper functions
function getParameter(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
function search(query,engine) {
    var searchengine = engine || $(".search-engine.selected a").attr("data-engine-shortname");
    var searchengineurl = $(".search-engine a[data-engine-shortname="+engine+"]").attr("data-engine-url") || $("#search-form").attr("action");
    var searchquery = query || $("#search-input").val();
    var currenturl = "?q=" + searchquery.split(' ').join('+') + "&engine=" + searchengine;
    var icon = $(".search-engine a[data-engine-shortname="+engine+"] img").attr("src") || $(".search-engine.selected a img").attr("src");
    if($.trim(searchquery) != "") {
        $("#results-frame").attr("src",searchengineurl + searchquery);
        $("title").html(searchquery + " - SmartSearch");
        history.replaceState(null, null, currenturl);
        if(engine) {
            $(".search-engine a[data-engine-shortname="+engine+"]").click();
        }
        $("#search-input").val(searchquery);
        $("#favourite-button").removeClass("starred disabled");
        if(bookmarks.check(searchquery,searchengine)) {
            $("#favourite-button").addClass("starred");
        }
    }
    else {
        $("title").html("SmartSearch");
        $("#favourite-button").addClass("disabled");
        $("#favourite-button").removeClass("starred");
        if(bookmarks.check(searchquery,searchengine)) {
            $("#favourite-button").addClass("starred");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please write here all the code, don't make us search for it.

Comment: create a test case demo in jsfiddle.net that represents your problem. Most people here won't dig through scripts on a full page to try to figure out what code is where...and where issue is

Comment: added the code in question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you refer the section of https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.2

> ```
>  reserved    = gen-delims / sub-delims
>
>  gen-delims  = ":" / "/" / "?" / "#" / "[" / "]" / "@"
>
>  sub-delims  = "!" / "$" / "&" / "'" / "(" / ")"
>              / "*" / "+" / "," / ";" / "="
> ```

The RFC goes on to say

> If data for a URI component would conflict with a reserved
> character's purpose as a delimiter, then the conflicting data must be
> percent-encoded before the URI is formed.

Comment: So what should i do before is : window.location.href = encodeURI(window.location.href) ?

Comment: You should use percent encoding , that is "foo#bar foobar" will be converted to "foo%23bar+foobar". Here is more info on best practice for using encodeURI --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75980/best-practice-escape-or-encodeuri-encodeuricomponent

Comment: Just tried this for percent encoding : `history.replaceState(null,null,encodeURIComponent(window.location.search));`
but it doesn't seem to work, the search field is empty instead.